# How to do a forced page refresh using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, page-refresh

In my automation, at one point I have to refresh the page to get the updated page content. But during the refresh the webpage is asking for a confirmation to resend the data (basically an alert is displayed on the page).

Even though I switched the focus to the alert and accepted it, the page contents are not getting refreshed. If I manually do the same, page contents are getting refreshed.

Is there any alternative way to refresh the page using Selenium Webdriver apart from navigate().refresh() command?

Or is there any way I can click on the Retry button on the alert without accepting the alert??

Comment: Why isn't navigate().refresh() sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I am testing this scenario in IE8 and navigate().refresh() doesn't refresh the page content.

Comment: Have you tried posting on any of the Selenium user groups with this one? Maybe it's a known bug...

Comment: The same question here with an awesome answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245641/refreshing-web-page-by-webdriver-when-waiting-for-specific-condition

Answer (score 2):

In ruby try using this - `@driver.switch_to.alert.accept`

this will click on Resend

java code `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Answer (score 2):

Refreshing Page in Selenium Webdriver using Java:

```
public boolean refresh()
{

    boolean executedActionStatus = false;       
    try{

        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.location.reload()");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        executedActionStatus = true;
    }
    catch(Exception er)
    {       
        er.printStackTrace();
        getScreenShot(method_TableName, "ExpCaseShot");
        log.error(er);
    }       
    return executedActionStatus;
}
```