# How to validate in selenium if a page is refreshing in every 5 seconds

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to validate if page refreshed successfully or not where page is refreshing every 5 seconds

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637123/selenium-ide-how-to-verify-assert-page-refresh). It could be your answer

Answer (score 0):

Pick an element on the page and wait for it to go stale using [`ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(e)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-).

For example,

```
WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(html));
// if you get here the page refreshed
```

If you need to know how fast the page refreshed, you will want to add a stopwatch and start it before and check the timing after. If you want to repeatedly check, you will want to put the code above in a loop, etc.