# How to implement refresh method by using web driver

Tags: selenium

How to implement the refresh by using web driver `public void refresh()`
When i used selenium rc i used directly defaultSelenium,refresh(); can any one suggest the beat alternative.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245641/refreshing-web-page-by-webdriver-when-waiting-for-specific-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use navigate() in webdriver. Example below:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

For refereshing the page -----

```
 Webdriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();// 
 driver.navigate().refresh();
```

using java method

```
public void refresh(){
driver.navigate().refresh();     
}
```