# How to solve the problems about python selenium to refresh all tabs?

Tags: python, selenium

I built python selenium script to open multiple tabs with the same URL.
I wanna refresh all tabs at once.
Please help me.

Comment: Could you please provide the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245641/refreshing-web-page-by-webdriver-when-waiting-for-specific-condition

Comment: Please Check My Answer!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Try This For Refresh Page:

```
driver.refresh()
```

And Also Re Open URL For Refresh:

```
driver.get('website.com')
```

Comment: I've used this way. but can't refresh all pages at once.