# How can I refresh a web page with Selenium in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, web, refresh

[I don't know how to fix the error, can somebody help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bGhX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Serilog;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverFlow.Answer.Selenium.RefreshPage
{
    class RefreshPage
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;      

        [Test]
        [Category("RefreshPage")]
        public void RefreshPageTest()
        {
            Log.Information("Get instance Chrome Browser");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), OptionsChrome());

            Log.Information("Acess your url site");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://YourUrlSite/index.aspx");

            Log.Information("Refresh page command");
            driver.Navigate().Refresh();
        }      

        private ChromeOptions OptionsChrome()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
            return chromeOptions;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong it should be, it's been some time since i touched selenium.

```cs
driver.Navigate().Refresh();
```

I searched a bit & this post from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245641/refreshing-web-page-by-webdriver-when-waiting-for-specific-condition) seem to back this up.

Answer (score 0):

It's an [issue with chrome web driver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23322/selenium-driver-service-not-found-exception), not with refreshing. If you didn't, you need to download chrome web driver or something might be wrong with your environment PATH variable.