# Python, Selenium: how to refresh page until element is present

Tags: python, selenium

```
while True:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div/button/div')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        browser.refresh()
```

Why do I still get `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button[2]"}` eroor?
I have imported the *NoSuchElementException* from *selenium.common.exceptions*.

Comment: Already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245641/refreshing-web-page-by-webdriver-when-waiting-for-specific-condition

Comment: @saty035 No, it doesn't answer this question

Comment: can you share the url or html?

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/cart/

Comment: HTML: https://dropmefiles.com/1NljW

Comment: @MikaelMikaelian what exactly element are you trying to locate there?

Comment: @Prophet
The green button that will apper
Like here
HTML: https://dropmefiles.com/tKq7P

Comment: I see. I can build the Xpath according to the text. It's not the best practice, but much better than your expression...

Comment: Can you also add the similar HTML for non-empty page there for that button disabled? Or you just trying to catch that button appearing?

Comment: I just try to catch when that button appearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
while True:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div/button/div')
        break
    except:
        browser.refresh
```

or maybe this:

```
while True:
    if(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div/button/div')):
        break
    else:
        browser.refresh
```

Pay attention, I'm using `find_elements` in the second code. It returns list. In case the list is non-empty it should enter the `if` else it will go into `else` and refresh the page

Comment: I updated the code. It should be `browser.refresh`, without the `()`

Comment: Did not help.
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button[2]"}`

Comment: Is there any other way I can refresh the page until the element is present?

Comment: Yes, but what I suggested should work too. So first of all I can't understand why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Check manually if your locator is the same after each refresh.

Comment: So it worked finally? What was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `time.sleep()` command after refreshing see if it works,

i guess it will because it instantly analyses the page after refreshing, because of which the page doesn't get time to fully load itself and throws error to you as it doesn't get the desired thing which it is searching for !

hope it helps !!!

```
while True:
    element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div/button/div')
    if element != None:
        print("got it !")
        break
    else:
        browser.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

or

```
for i in range(1):
    while True:
    element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div/button/div')
    if element != None:
        print("got it !")
        break
    else:
        browser.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

Comment: Unfortunately, did not help.